# Clarification on opening a Flexible Savings Account

Tags: united-states, fsa

I haven't opened the FSA account during the open enrollment period. Now I have some medical expenses. I might have to pay more than $500 from my own pocket.

When I checked with my insurance agent, he mentioned that I am not eligible.

Is it possible to open an FSA when I am out of the enrollment period?

Comment: Since you cannot enroll in the FSA, do you know if you are eligible for an HSA? If yes, and if you aren't currently taking advantage of it, you may be able to accomplish the same benefit as the FSA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. First, I don't know what "Insurance Agent" means. It's your employer that handles FSA. Usually the HR department.

You have a defined block of time to enroll. If you missed it, it's only a qualifying event that might allow you to charge coverage.

Comment: Yes, I mean to say "Insurance Agent" for my Payroll processing company. So i have to conclude that i missed this year to open the FSA account. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes. Qualifying events include marriage, divorce, birth of a child, etc. But the normal time has passed.